# Sending files from server to client with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf, sockets, networking, ftp

I am developing a C# ASP.NET 4.0 application that will reside on a Windows Server 2003. By mean of accessing this application through a network computer, any user would be able to upload files to the windows server. But also, once these files are stored on server, he/she would be able to copy these files from the windows server to another networked computer.

I have found a way to upload files to a specified location on the server disk, 
but now I need to send these files that are on server disk to the client computers.

My question is: Is there any way to send or copy files from server to other client computers (not the one that is accessing the web service) without needing a program recieving those files on the client computers?  FTP, WCF, cmd commands, sockets?

Any idea?

Comment: As in, you want the server to automatically disseminate the file to the client PC(s)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to install a FileZilla FTP server on each client computer and my page is working very well. But another option is to create a work group in the windows server and put every client computer to work in this work group, so that Windows server have access to the computers in the same work group.
Here are some links that may help to create the work groups:

http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/cannot-see-other-computers-on-network-in-my-network-places/
http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-2003/server-2003-workgroup-setup-/1004.html

Answer (score 1):

Over a LAN, if you have the correct permissions and so on, you can write to a disk on a different machine using File.Copy -- there's nothing special about that.

If we're talking about remote machines over the internet, that's a different story. Something has to be listening whether it's FTP, WCF, DropBox, etc.

If the problem is that it can be painful to get something like WCF to work from a client due to problems like firewall issues under Windows 7, you could take a different route and have the client periodically ping the server looking for new content. To give the server a point of reference, the ping could contain the name or creation date of the most recent file received. The server could reply with a list of new files, and then the client could make several WCF calls, one by one, to pull the content down. This pattern keeps all the client traffic outbound.

Comment: @user766283: what kind of error did you get? permissions? timeout?

Comment: @user766283: also, how big are the files?

Comment: Server is in the same network that clients, but I have tried the copy file operation: File.Copy(@"c:/pathforlocalfile",@"\\targetmachinepath.fileExt"); But an exception occurs, so I guess that is over an internet protocols

Comment: The error that comes out is:

//The network path was not found.

But I don't understand why this exception is thrown, because access to path is granted to write and read over network locations.

And files are MS Power Points and text files.

Comment: @beb_lm: Well, it does sound like a networking or permissions issue. File.Copy does work in this situation. I would double check (a) that the path is actually valid for that user from that box and (b) that you've given permissions to the correct user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want users of your webapp to download files, I'd look into an "ashx generic handler." It will allow you to send files back down to clients over HTTP(s).

If you are looking to have remote users, tell your webserver to copy files to other servers ON THE SAME LAN AS THE SERVER, you would write using normal System.IO operations.

Comment: Target machines are simple computers, that are running Windows 7 OS (they don't have a ftp server configuration running on them). So, when I try to put files on them by mean of System.IO operations an exception is thrown. 

Can you explain a little bit more about the "ashx generic handler" structure. I am a little confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you can run the program as an account that has access to that computer.  However having this sort of access on your network that would grant access to the outside world to put an unfiltered file on your internal network is just asking to be hacked.

Comment: Security problems are not an issue, access to the page requires user name and password, and the server is connected over a local network( internet users can't access the application). How can it be possible?

Comment: User names and passwords get hacked (usually because they are weak, reused across multiple sites, and not safeguarded properly).  You are going to give unrestricted access to a program that will have the ability to put ANY file on ANY computer on your network.  Being behind a firewall is good until someone gets through it.  What you want to do is possible on a windows network because every drive has a hidden root share that allows admins to access it remotely if needed.  To do so requires "GOD" rights on your network.  So you would need to give your program those rights to access it.